# Display posts from a different website on Genesis Responsive Slider

Tags: posts, blog, responsive, genesis-theme-framework, slideshow

In the homepage of [this website](https://goncaloperes.com), I have the widget "Genesis - Responsive Slider".

[image]

From the "Genesis - Responsive Slider" Settings, one can see that it is picking up the posts from this website.

[image]

However, I wonder if, instead of picking up the posts from this website, it can pick the posts from [this other website](https://notes.goncaloperes.com) (whose parent theme is also the Genesis Framework) and display them in the slider.

If yes, how should one proceed?